# Funcion SQL en PgAdmin

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

tengo que hacer un ejercicio en donde debo crear una funcion para determinar la cantidad de ventas por cliente de una tabla. No estoy entendiendo bien como se formula la funcion. Yo tengo a dni como campo para individualizar al cliente dentro de esa tabla de ventas, entiendo que deberia hacer un count para ver cuantas veces aparece cada dni en la tabla para asi determinar la cantidad de ventas pero no se como integrar eso a una funcion

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado

Answer (score 0):

Debes valerte de la cláusula `create function` para crear una nueva función. Su sintaxis básica, de acuerdo a la [documentación] es:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] FUNCTION
    name ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [ { DEFAULT | = } default_expr ] [, ...] ] )
    [ RETURNS rettype | RETURNS TABLE ( column_name column_type [, ...] ) ]
```

Aplicandolo para tu necesidad, y suponiendo que el `dni` es de tipo texto, una función básica que devuelva el contador de *ventas* para un `dni` luciría más o menos como:

```
CREATE FUNCTION contar_ventas(Adni TEXT)
RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE contador integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(1) INTO contador
    FROM ventas
   WHERE dni = $1;

  RETURN contador;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Es probable que se me haya escapado algún error de sintaxis, ya que he escrito el código en el navegador y no tengo forma de probarlo ahora mismo. Si tienes algún inconveniente, acude a la documentación o deja un comentario.

Comment: disculpa la ignorancia, pero la condicion where "dni = $ " que significa ?

Comment: es `dni = $1` donde `$1` es el primer parámetro recibido en la función.